# Save order of columns in localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-sortable-hoc

I am using `react-sortable-hoc` library in React to create a layout with draggable columns.

I need to save the order of columns once dragged by user, to the localStorage, and retrieve their order after page reload.

From state I can get these columns and then do
`localStorage.setItem('dragged', JSON.stringify({ items }));`
which saves my two columns like this:

`0: {key: null, ref: null, props: {}, _owner: null, _store: {}}`
`1: {key: null, ref: null, props: {}, _owner: null, _store: {}}`

I'm trying to adapt the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190752/is-it-possible-to-save-the-order-of-the-column-of-material-table-to-a-database-t) except I'm not using material table. And on `items.push(savedColumns[columnIndex]);` react throws this:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

which I can't find a solution to.

How do I properly save the order of columns and render it after page reload?

---

### My code in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { sortableContainer, sortableElement } from 'react-sortable-hoc';
import arrayMove from 'array-move';
import './App.css';
import CircleImage from './components/CircleImage';
import InstaPost from './components/InstaPost';
import Editable from './components/Editable';

const DraggableColumn = sortableElement(({ value }) => <div className="draggable-column">{value}</div>);

const SortableContainer = sortableContainer(({ children }) => {
  return <div className="draggable-container">{children}</div>;
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [<CircleImage />, <InstaPost />]
  };

  onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    this.setState(({ items }) => ({
      items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    if (localStorage.getItem('dragged') === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('dragged', JSON.stringify({ items }));
    }
    console.log(items);

    let savedColumns = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dragged'));
    for (var columnIndex in savedColumns) {
      items.push(savedColumns[columnIndex]);
    }

    function handleColumnDrag(sourceIndex, destinationIndex) {
      const sourceColumn = savedColumns[sourceIndex];
      const destinationColumn = savedColumns[destinationIndex];

      // Swapping the column order
      savedColumns[sourceIndex] = destinationColumn;
      savedColumns[destinationIndex] = sourceColumn;
      localStorage.setItem('dragged', JSON.stringify(savedColumns));
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="column">
            <Editable />
          </div>
          <SortableContainer onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} axis="x" lockAxis="x">
            {items.map((value, index) => (
              <DraggableColumn key={`item-${index}`} index={index} value={value} />
            ))}
          </SortableContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Share your code if it's possible.

Comment: Shared my App.js, thanks for having a look

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing 
`for (var columnIndex in savedColumns) {
   items.push(savedColumns[columnIndex]);
}`
It is completely unnecessary. Just do `items = savedColumns;`

check if the item type in `JSON.stringify(item)` while doing setItem is the same as `this.state.item`. Then when you do a getItem and parse it, it will not throw an error

I am adding this link with the [Minimal reproducible code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-dhawan-s6q9f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) If you want to make changes to it if it doesn't work for you. As, I can't see any invocation of `handleColumnDrag` I feel like you might stumble into some other problems which you haven't shown in the above code

Comment: Using `items.push()` because can't reassign directly to `const { items } = this.state;`. Even if I change it to `let`, I get "Objects are not valid as a React child" if I do `items = savedColumns;`.

Comment: Thanks for creating a codesandbox, that was the boilerplate I started from, to adapt to my solution. Yes `handleColumnDrag` will be called in my <DraggableColumn /> component, probably from a prop `onColumnDragged` which I don't know yet how to implement. But in codesandbox I can't see where the items' order is saved to localStorage am I missing something?

Comment: Go to console tab and do localStorage.get the key. Or you can console.log the variable and check.also why do you need to push? It the function in codebox where I do localStorage.set , It stores the correct item for me